# JQuery doesn't work in production environment

Tags: jquery, grails

For about 3 months I learn Grails and I developed my first full application alone. I deployed it on a tomcat server (Tomcat6). For that I use **grails war** first and then I put **myApplic.war** in the tomcat's **webapps** directory. The application is correctly deployed BUT in my page the autocomplete from JQUery-UI doesn't work at the moment (in development it works well). I  used the JQuery and JQuery-UI plugins (I added them in my **BuildConfig.groovy**) and when I display the source code of my page I got something like that :

```
<script src="/CoiffureV2-0.1/static/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<link href="/CoiffureV2-0.1/static/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.24/jquery-ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />
<script src="/CoiffureV2-0.1/static/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.24/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<link href="/CoiffureV2-0.1/static/plugins/twitter-bootstrap-2.3.2/less/bootstrap.less.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" order="100" />
```

So it seems that JQuery is correctly included. What can I do to solve my problem ? Any idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards,

Hito

Comment: At first, you could use grails resources plugin.
Any errors at dev tools?

Comment: Have you tried to query "/CoiffureV2-0.1/static/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" directly to see if jquery js file is present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the resources program if it's not already in your project.  Then, you have two options:

### If your page uses a layout like main.gsp

This is the case if your .gsp page has something like `<meta name="layout" content="main"/>` inside `<head>`.

1. Add the following to the beginning of the `<head>` section of individual .gsp pages that need JQuery and JQuery UI:

   `<r:require modules="jquery,jquery-ui"/>`
2. Then, right before `</head>` in `main.gsp` add:

   `<r:layoutResources/>`
3. Then right before `</body>` in `main.gsp` add:

   `<r:layoutResources/>`
4. Remove your old `<script>` and `<link>` tags.

### Or, if you don't have a layout:

1. Put this inside `<head>` on .gsp pages that need JQuery:

   `<r:require modules="jquery,jquery-ui"/>`

   `<r:layoutResources/>`
2. And put this right before `</body>`

   `<r:layoutResources/>`
3. Remove your old `<script>` and `<link>` tags.

Example: http://pastebin.com/K0LU4sqG

---

Resources plugin documentation: http://grails.org/plugin/resources

Comment: I will try this. I included all my custom JS like that : <g:javascript src="client/update.js" />   . Is it correct ? I put it just before the </body> tag.

Comment: Grails doesn't always put javascript files in the directory you expect.  Try something like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'client', file: 'update.js')}"></script>` where "client" is a folder inside your project's "web-app" folder.